# Java's JOptionsPane dialog window too small?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I created a Panel to allow some user input. This panel needs to come over the application's main window which is usually marked as 'alwaysOnTop'. So the input panel is shown using `JOptionPane` like this:

```
ConfigurationPanel cp = new ConfigurationPanel();
cp.setDuration(total);
JWindow window = (JWindow) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(TimerPanel.this);
window.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(TimerPanel.this, cp, "Settings", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION) == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    // if successfull, take data
    try {
        total = cp.getDuration();
        savePreferences();
        reset();
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

The ConfigurationPanel has been created with the NetBeans GUI builder which has not failed me in 20 years, so I never actually checked. But since it was mentioned I checked and the cnnstructor calls initComponents(), which in turn contains these lines:

```
    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
```

This is what the panel itself shall look like (screenshot from Netbeans IDE):

[image]

And this is what the combination looks like at runtime:

[image]

Why are the main buttons Ok and Cancel not properly visible? This has worked in the past, and it seems the problem comes from outside my code...

This seems to happen both on Windows 10 based Oracle Java 13.0.1+9 and 15.0.1+9-18 and OpenJDK 16.0.1+9-24.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I checked the component and it is on the default GroupLayout.

Comment: For what it's worth, I cannot reproduce your problem. Maybe the time has come to post the code generated by NetBeans GUI builder, i.e. the code of class `ConfigurationPanel`. Or better yet, post a [mcve], as @AndrewThompson wrote in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631893/javas-joptionspane-dialog-window-too-small#comment119546013_67631893).

Comment: So something really strange is going on. Despite the fact that the project worked for a long time already, I cannot open the ConfigurationPanel myself. The IDE freezes trying to open that file. There must be something else that I need to check...

Comment: *"The IDE freezes trying to open that file."*One or the many reasons most people generally don't use IDE based 'GUI builders'. In this case, if an IDE starts to misbehave, they'd simply create a new project to transfer the code to, or use a different IDE. Good luck with it though, I don't provide IDE support.

Comment: I resolved the issue after fixing the IDE (am running latest available Netbeans 12.3 with latest supported JDK now). Then I was able to open the panel again. The problem I descibed above was still there. Then I switched the panel from GroupLayout to GridBagLayout and the dialog looks suitable again.
Not sure who suggested to check the layout, but I would accept that as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from GroupLayout (Netbeans' default layout) to GridBagLayout resolved the issue.